# (Android) Java get value from SQLDatabase

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi i'm working on an application and I've just started toying with SQL I've set up a database with all my information and what not now i need to be able to get the values and i haven't been able to figure it out.

What I'd like is a java method which i can pass the column name and row id and have it return the value.

For instance if my table were like this

```
--------------
| _id | data |
--------------
| 1   | cat  |
| 2   | dog  |
| 3   | fish |
--------------
```

I would like to call the method say getValue(2, data); and it would return dog any help with this would be greatly appreciated as i haven't been able to figure this seemingly easy problem out

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String result;
String[] cols = new String[] { "data" };
String[] args = new String[] { id };
Cursor cursor = mSqliteDb.query(MY_TABLE, cols, "_id = ?", args, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToNext())
    result = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();
```

`MY_TABLE` is the table you are querying, `cols` is a `String` array containing the columns you're retrieving, and `args` is a `String` array containing the ID argument.

Answer (score 1):

The [Developer Documents](http://developer.android.com/) are an excellent resource. They are heavily documented and contain easy to follow tutorials. Try starting here.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can follow these steps:

1. retrieve database reference
2. perform a query, obtaining a cursor
3. set cursor position to first element

...and write the following code:

```
String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
```

Then, you have to close your cursor calling: `cursor.close();`

In this way you can easily retrieve all your data.